# Solving recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n^{1/2}) + O(\log\log\log(n))$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity, data-structure

I'm trying to solve the recurrence

$$T(n) = 2T(n^{1/2}) + O(\log\log\log(n))$$

but I don't know how to do it because of the $O(\log\log\log(n))$

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.
Thanks.

This is what I did:

$$T(n^{1/2^k})+ \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} O(\log\log\log(n^{1/2^j})$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgotten the effect of the $2$ in $2T(\sqrt{n})$.

You should instead get $$ T(n) = 2^k T(n^{1/2^k}) + O\left(\sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} 2^{j} \log\log\log n^{1/2^j}\right)$$

Now, trivialising the $n^{1/2k}$ in the first term takes $k = \log\log n$ [1]. Then the first term clearly scales as $\log n$. The logs in the second have the following behaviour: $$ \log\log\log n^{1/{2^j}} = \log \log (\log(n)/2^j) = \log( \log\log n - j).$$ This tells us that us that the second term scales as $$ \sum_{j = 0}^{\log\log n -1} 2^j \log(\log\log n - j).$$

It should be easy to see that this term is going to dominate the complexity, since the $j = \log\log n - 2$ term in the sum is $\Omega(\log n).$ So, we need to get a handle on this sum.

For convenience, let me redefine this sum a function of a generic variable $m$ (which avoids having to type $\log\log$ all the time). Let $$ f(m) :=  \sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} 2^j \log (m-j),$$ which we shall proceed to upper bound. To this end, observe that the function $2^x \log(m-x)$ increases for $x \le m-3$ (the $-3$ isn't so important - it should however be evident that the function increases up to $j \le m - C$ for some $O(1)$ constant $C$). This means that $$ f(m) \le 2^{m-2} \log 2 + \int_{x = 0}^{m-3} 2^x \log(m-x) \mathrm{d}x \\
= \Theta(2^m) + 2^{m-3} \int_{y = 0}^{m-3} 2^{-y} \log(3 + y)\mathrm{d}y \\ \le \Theta(2^m) + \Theta(2^m) \int_{y = 0}^\infty 2^{-y}\log(3+y) \mathrm{d}y.$$ It should be straightforward to argue that the final integral above is bounded. So we end up with $f(m) = \Theta(2^m)$. This in turn means that $T(n) = O( f(\log\log n)) = O(\log n)$.

---

[1] To clarify this point, which came up in the comments: in the relation $T(n) = 2^k T(n^{1/2^k})) + \cdots,$ we have $T$ of some function of $n$ on both sides. To control $T$ itself, we need to reduce the $T(n^{1/2^k})$ on the right hand side to some value of $T$ upon which we already have control. Typically, it is assumed that for constant sized problems, $T$ is a constant. So, if we take $k$ so large that $n^{1/2^k} \le C$ (think of $C$ as just $1$ or $2$ if you like), then we'll have a $2^k T(C)$ bound, and now we can treat $T(C)$ as just a constant. This is what I mean by trivialising the $n^{1/2^k}$. In this particular case, to ensure that $n^{1/{2^k}} < 2,$ say, we need to take $k > \log\log n - \log\log 2$. For convenience, we can just set this to $\log\log n$ (or I guess ceiling or floor of that - it doesn't really matter, since asymptotics are usually not sensitive to such small perturbations).

Comment: so what should we do if the question was $$T(n) = T(n^{1/2}) + O(\log\log\log(n))$$ ?

Comment: @anita It'd be something similar - you'll still need to take $k \sim \log\log n,$ and so you'll end up with the sum $\sum_{j  = 0}^{\log\log n - 1} \log(\log\log n - j)$. Again, set $m = \log\log n$. The function of interest is $\sum_{j = 0}^{m-1} \log(m-j) = \sum_{j = 1}^m \log(j)$. This is also monotone, and you can bound by an integral.

Comment: I have another problem also, I can't understand how you found that k=loglogn?

Comment: You have a relation in terms of  $T(n^{1/2^k}).$ You need to bring the argument of $T$ here down to a constant to remove dependence on $n$ in this term. So, you need $k$ such that  $n^{1/2^k} \le C$ for some constant $C$. But, taking logs, this is equivalent to $\frac{\log n}{2^k} \le \log C \iff 2^k \ge \log n / \log C \iff k \ge \log\log n - \log\log C$. Taking just $k = \log\log n$ is a matter of convenience.

Comment: why $$n^{1/2^{k}}=logn/2^{k}$$?

Comment: No, I'm taking logs. $\log a^b = b \log a$ - I edited the previous comment to make this explicit.

Comment: thank you so much I understood it.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped.

Comment: excuse me but I'm trying to solve this problem for
T(n)=T(n1/2)+O(logloglog(n))
I found O(loglognlog(loglogn)) but it is really strange!

Comment: Looks right to me. Why do you find it strange?

Comment: really it's right? Thank you so much